# Solving system of inequalities and equations with Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I want to the use `Reduce` to solve a system of equations and inequalities. In particular, I am looking for the conditions for which:

$$
\left(\alpha\frac{B-K_R}{p_e}\right)^\alpha\ [(1-\alpha)(B-K_R\ )]^{1-\alpha}<\left(\alpha \frac{B-K_F}{p_e+\tau\gamma_F} \right)^\alpha\ [(1-\alpha)(B-K_F\ )]^{1-\alpha}.
$$

Using the command below works fine.

```
(* Code 1 *)
uR = ((1 - α) (B - KR))^(1 - α)*((α (B - KR))/pe)^α;
uF = ((1 - α) (B - KF))^(1 - α)*((α (B - KF))/(pe + t γF))^α;

Reduce[{uF < uR, α == 1/2, KR > KF > 0, γF > 0, γR == 0, 
 {B, τ, pe} > {0, 0, 0}}, {KR, B, τ}]
```

However, when I use `0 < α < 1` instead of `α == 1/2`:

```
(* Code 2 *)
Reduce[{uF < uR, 0 < α < 1, KR > KF > 0, γF > 0, γR == 0, 
 {B, τ, pe} > {0, 0, 0}}, {KR, B, τ}]
```

Mathematica does not seem to be able to solve the problem, at least that is what I assume since it is running for a very long time (more than 24 hours). The thing is that I am able to solve the problem manually, and when I set $\alpha=1/2$, I end up with the same result as Mathematica. So I know that there exists a solution.

Is there a possibility to enhance my code (Code2), such that I get a result?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! It is desirable that you include the whole code that you use (select, right-click, then _Copy as Input Text_) so that others can run the code. I have edited your question and included the definition of `uF` and `uR`. Please check that they are correct.

Comment: @Domen - It appears that the OP used different notation in the subsequent code. For example, `Subscript[K, R]` appears to be `KR`

Comment: The term Subscript[τγ, F] looks suspicious. Is this τ* Subscript[γ, F]? You should definitely rewrite this without all the Subscripts.

Comment: @BobHanlon, oh, right, thanks, I should have been more careful! bills, this is my mistake as I have edited the question.

Comment: Thank you all for enhancing my post! The definitions for `uF` and `uR` are now correct.